# Drools Rule Engine Inquiry

Tags: drools

I am currently using a version of Drools Business Rules Management System that appears to have a rule limitation of around 350 rules (max). Can someone clarify if the rules engine in the latest version of Drools Business Rules Management System (Version 8.32.0 from 12/16/2022 or even Version 7.73.0) has a greater capacity for number of rules?

1. What is the rules limitation for these two versions of Drools Business Rules Management System?
2. Would there be large downtime in replacing one version of Drools with a newer version of Drools?

Looking to understand more on the above as I am fast approaching the number of rules for this BRMS.

Comment: What makes you think that there is a limitation? Are you getting any specific error?

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit to the number of rules you can have, as long as your application has sufficient memory to read them into memory, and sufficient CPU to do any expensive processing that you might ask it to do.

I previously maintained an application which hosted 1.5 million Drools rules. It worked like that with Drools 5, and then continued working like that when I upgraded to Drools 7. (Drools 8 had not been released at the time, but there's no indication that it has degraded in capabilities at all.)

Replacing one Drools version with another depends on what the version change is. When we upgraded from Drools 5 to Drools 7, it was effectively a rewrite. A change within a major version of Drools prior to 7.44 (or thereabouts) is trivial because Drools honored semver backwards-compatibility guarantees between minor versions. More recent versions of Drools should still be simple to change within a major version, but you'll need to do testing since there's no guarantees of backwards compatibility anymore. The Drools documentation should guide you on how to do a major version upgrade (7 -> 8) but if you need to go more than 1 major version it's likely a rewrite.

Your downtime for an upgrade is therefore the time your developers need to do any necessary code changes, the time you need to verify your functionality, and then the time necessary for the service to read the rules into memory (on startup or whenever.)

<sub>Of course if you're running your existing instances and then only cut-over to the new upgraded instance once it's ready, there's no visible downtime from an end-user's perspective.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

there shouldn’t be any limitations in the number or rules. You might be hitting a memory limitation of your app. Drools is memory intensive to do the evaluations, that means that it sacrifice memory to be able to perform fast evaluations.
If you are using drools as a library in your app that is hosting the rules, changing the version of drools means that you will need to load the rules and the data again.

Comment: Does Drools rule engine which contains the rules have a memory limitation then and not a limit on number of rules? Do new versions of Drools have rule engines which would not encounter this problem by having more memory?

Comment: As with any process that you run in any machine/virtual machine there will be always a memory limitation. In the case of drools that is limited by the JVM memory allocation, so I would say that it is not related to drools at all.